# how to ensure effects of animation noise modifier only get applied in the positive direction?

Tags: animation, graph-editor

i have a generator applying a straight line to the animation. i want noise variation in this by adding noise modifier. however, the modifier causes the red curve (generator and noise modifier) to go both above and below the green line (only generator). im looking for how to ensure the effects of the noise is only in the positive direction( i.e. the noise is applied only above the green line)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just choose "add" instead of "replace" as blend type of noise, and you get:

[image]

[image]